# Is it possible to read HttpRequest parameters without consuming stream?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I am looking at the implementation of the HiddenMethodFilter in sitebricks [here](https://github.com/usmanismail/sitebricks/blob/ec106ea572bb58e8769cf0f4d1f6df54fd601521/sitebricks/src/main/java/com/google/sitebricks/HiddenMethodFilter.java):

At line 65 there is the following code:

```
try {
    String methodName = httpRequest.getParameter(this.hiddenFieldName);
    if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(httpRequest.getMethod()) && !Strings.empty(methodName)) {
    ....
```

It checks if a specific parameter was set and uses that to wrap the request. However, in reading that parameter it will consume the stream  and the eventual servlet will not be able read any data.

What would be the best way to avoid this? I implemented the HttpServletRequestWrapper [here](https://github.com/usmanismail/sitebricks/blob/7bed9a6886f6b8702e40530b2130c7fb5abc5fc2/sitebricks/src/main/java/com/google/sitebricks/HiddenMethodFilter.java) which reads the contents of the stream into a byte array. This however may use a lot of memory to store the requests.

```
private HttpServletRequestWrapper getWrappedRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, final byte[] reqBytes)
   throws IOException {

final ByteArrayInputStream byteInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(reqBytes);
return new HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpRequest) {

  @Override
  public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    ServletInputStream sis = new ServletInputStream() {

      @Override
      public int read() throws IOException {
        return byteInput.read();
      }
    };
    return sis;
  }
};
}
```

Is there a better way? can we read the parameter without consuming the stream? (Some thing similar to peek) can we reset the stream?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `POST` requests and read parameters from the `httpRequest` this will affect the `InputStream` and you will have problems in other parts needing to read it.
This is stated in [ServletRequest#getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)javadoc:

> If the parameter data was sent in the request body, such as occurs
>   with an HTTP POST request, then reading the body directly via
>   getInputStream() or getReader() can interfere with the execution of
>   this method.

The `ServletInputStream` is derived from `InputStream` and inherits the `markSupported` `reset` etc which are actually no-ops and so you can not reset a `ServletInputStream`.
This means that you will have to consume it.

Comment: Are there any alternative ways to get meta data from a web page to a servlet container which does not require data to be in the request body?

Comment: Use GET instead of POST. Or look for an alternate approach for the particular functional requirement so that you don't need to read the body multiple times.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail:Read the inputstream once, buffer it and pass it arround to the various components that would need to read it

Comment: @Jim Already there just wondering if there is a better solution that does not require buffering potentially very large data.